# Are partial response un-RESTful

Tags: rest, ember.js

During a discussion for designing our REST api's one of the fellow developer told that partial responses are not RESTful.
e.g. While returning response for /forums/{forum_id}/users I am just returning user name and avatar pic.
When somebody wants detailed info about user I send {age, location, points_scored etc. etc.}.
While trying to model this using ember-data we landed up in the problem mentioned at https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/51
Thats when the developer pointed out that partial responses are against RESTful design. But I could not find any such information in any of the REST books or on Internet. Moreover I found that google actually uses partial responses in their RESTful API's and there are many guys using it.

So wanted to know are partial responses (like the above) really not recommended for RESTful services or its just a design choice issue.

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to a common misconception, REST does not oblige you to read and write the same exact resources.

CouchDB is a really good example for the way to go. It handles:

- "objects" (a.k.a. "documents") that can be *created*, *read*, *updated*, and *deleted*,
- and "views", which are computed from documents, that can only be *read*.

In your case, `/forums/01a0/users` would be a "view", while `/user/99a7` would be an "object".

Comment: Hi Aurélien, What you are saying is fine. But I wanted to know is that  If I am returning partial view of a resource (e.g. just returning name of a Person) in my API then am I going against REST principle's?

Comment: @Rahul In the "view" that lists the users of the forum, you could definitely have partial information (such as name and avatar picture) about each user.

Comment: What is a pain (esp. for cache) is when you mix data coming from other resources in an updatable resource. The problem is much simpler with read-only "views".